# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable scipy.spatial.ckdtree

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

I am following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956149/python-sum-lat-lon-points-within-geographic-radius-and-sum-to-grid). Everything was fine until I imported this.

```
import scipy.spatial.ckdtree as spsp
```

After running this by following the instructions given in the link above. I did this

```
kdtrees = [spsp(p) for p in coordinates]
```

I got an error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

SO this is what my cooridinates outout looks like:

```
coordinates = []
for row in result:
    coordinates.append(np.array(row, dtype=float))

print coordinates
Output :[array([ 28.6333,  77.2167]), array([ 28.6333,  77.25  ])]
```

I don't know where I am going wrong. I followed the instructions as it is as given in the link.

Answer (score 2):

You import `import scipy.spatial.ckdtree` as `spsp`. That doesn't change the fact that `scipy.spatial.ckdtree` is a module and not a callable.

Try importing `cKDTree` from `import scipy.spatial.ckdtree`, like this:

```
from scipy.spatial.ckdtree import cKDTree as spsp
...
kdtrees = [spsp(p) for p in coordinates]
```